# Android ActionBar appears after clicking settings

Tags: android

Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.start_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

start_activity.actions.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_collection"
    android:title="@string/action_collection"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_collection"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

My menu appears only after clicking settings button. It's not visibile on launch. How to change it ?

Comment: what do you mean settings button?

Comment: Are you referring to the Menu button? If you are using a Samsung phone, it won't show up.

Comment: yes, i mean menu button. you want me to tell that on samsung it doesnt work ? please...there must be some solution. im using lg g2 and galaxy 10.1 , on both i cannot see menu loaded a tthe top of the screen, it appears only after clicking menu. adding custom xmlns like below xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"> and setting custom:showsAsAction="always" didnt help.

Answer (score 2):

If You have extend the activity to android.app.Activity; then the menu xml you have should work.

If your using support library android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity then to display the action menus in action bar, change your menu xml like below..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    custom:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_collection"
    android:title="@string/action_collection"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_collection"
    custom:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: im getting error now on android studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:

Comment: no error. i have used instead of 'custom' name of my app and there is no error. i just cannot use this

Comment: it doesnt work with custom and even with app name or namespace. i have tried everything excatly like you said. with you code given above i cannot make project in android studio . im getting :app:rpcessDebugResources error execution failed

Comment: Does your activity extend ActionBarActivity or Activity ? . see my updated answer

Comment: no it doesnt. should i extend my activity by actionbaractivity ?

Comment: Yes extend activity to ActionBarActivity, if your using the menu xml i shared

Comment: I have also added this code dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
} but now app crashes on launch. heh

Comment: Good. Accept the answer .. might help others